# VS_VERSION_INFO not showing in Windows Explorer after switching to Windows SDK Resource Compiler

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, explorer, fileversioninfo, delphi-11-alexandria

I use a RC (resource) file to get version information linked into the EXE file, and recently I switched from *Borland Resource Compiler* to *Windows SDK Resource Compiler*, in order to be able to use multiple sizes icons in my application.

The icon worked, but now when I compile my application the resource information seems to not be attached to the EXE file. I'm suspecting that the same RC file that works for BRCC32.EXE does not work for the Windows SDK Resource Compiler.

Here is my `verinfo.rc` content:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION             1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION          1,0,0,0
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
        VALUE "Comments",         "Company Soft\0"
        VALUE "CompanyName",      "Company2\0"
        VALUE "FileDescription",  "Company Soft\0"
        VALUE "FileVersion",      "x.x.x.x\0"
        VALUE "InternalName",     "Company Soft\0"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright",   "Company2\0"
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "abrev.exe\0"
        VALUE "ProductName",      "Company Soft\0"
        VALUE "ProductVersion",   "x.x.x.x\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0409,1200
    END
END
```

And here is how my EXE file shows in Explorer's file properties:
[image: Explorer file properties showing no EXE version information]

Finally, I'm not forgetting to use the `verinfo.rc` file in my Delphi project file:

```
program myprogram;
{$R 'verinfo.res' 'verinfo.rc'}
```

### Update #1

If I change the resource compiler back from *Windows SDK Compiler* to *Borland Resource Compiler* the version information is included into the EXE file (but I cannot use multiple sizes icons anymore):
[image: Delphi project settings: Resource Compiler]
[image: Explorer file properties showing EXE version information as wanted]

### Update #2

Using the resource editor [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) I can see there is indeed version information resource in the EXE file. But I can't see this in Windows Explorer, and also can't retrieve this with a WinAPI function like [GetFileVersionInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286050/4299358):
[image: Resource Hacker displays VS_VERSION_INFO resource]

### Update #3

Here is what I found what happens when using the same RC file but with different resource compilers:

1. When using *Borland Resource Compiler* everything works fine, with the version info shown in Windows Explorer; Resource Hacker shows this:

   > [image: Resource Hacker showing resource "1"]
2. When using *Windows SDK Resource Compiler* version information still shows in Resource Hacker **but not** in Windows Explorer:

   > [image: Resource Hacker showing resource "VS_VERSION_INFO"]

Comment: Are you building through the IDE? If so, maybe your verinfo.rc data gets overridden by the Project Options' version data?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Both from IDE or command line, i get the same problem... The box 'Include version information in project' on Project options > Application > Version info is NOT checked

Comment: What if you change `040904b0` to `040904E4`? And `VALUE "Translation", 0x0409 0x04E4` at the bottom?

Comment: Tried this, but still empty details on EXE property. It's strange because this same .rc file always worked for me, until i switched the resource compiler

Comment: Ahem: "_always_" = [for less than 2 months](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69485477/4299358). Have you looked into the EXE with a hex editor to search for expected strings? Just because _Explorer_ isn't displaying version info doesn't mean it's not in the file.

Comment: Even better: A resource editor.

Comment: @AmigoJack The issue on the question you mentioned was not the same on this question ; it was a problem related to invalid chars being shown, but the version information was always there. Now the problem is simply no information is attached to the EXE

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I tried to use this function on Delphi to get version info, and no information is retrieved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279394/getfileversioninfosize-and-getfileversioninfo-return-nothing/17286050#17286050

Comment: UPDATE : I can confirm that if change the resource compiler back to Borland Resource Compiler, version info goes back to EXE file. I'll update the question

Comment: Maybe i need to use Windows SDK recource compiler to the icon file and Borland to the version info ?

Comment: Microsoft SDK resource compiler handles the RC files a bit differently. You can read about some of the differences in [Delphi documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/RC.EXE,_the_Microsoft_SDK_Resource_Compiler)

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the suggestion, i tried this instead of the one on my question, but still, no version information attached to EXE unless i use the Borland Resource Compiler instead of Windows SDK one

Comment: UPDATE 2 on question

Comment: @TomBrunberg You mean add \n instead of \0 ?

Comment: UPDATE 3 on question

Comment: That's the proof: you wrongly assumed that the resource is not inside the EXE just because Explorer didn't display it. Looking into a hex editor should be the 1st step, looking into a resource editor the 2nd. First verify that the linker does its job, then verify the resource format is correct.

Comment: @AmigoJack You are right, the resource was in the EXE. That's why i did the update 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version resource in DLL not visible with right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874152/1718632) fixed the issue: Basically I changed the first line of my `.rc` file from

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
```

to

```
1 VERSIONINFO
```

Now everything works!

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource#parameters) it should always be `1`.

Comment: Well done for sorting this out for yourself!

Comment: @AmigoJack It's odd because if i use the Borland Resource Compiler, it will work the other way. Anyway, thanks for the info

Comment: This implies that the `VS_VERSION_INFO` identifier is not being defined by the resource compiler, so the `.rc` script needs to do it explicitly, eg: `#ifndef VS_VERSION_INFO #define VS_VERSION_INFO 1 #endif`. When declaring a resource, if its ID is not a numeric value, it will be used as-is as a string name instead. You can clearly see this happening in your screenshots.