# VERSIONINFO structure in the resource file

Tags: delphi, fileversioninfo

I would like to change the content of the program version, program name, author, etc. during compilation in the command line.

I didn't find a way to change it other than using my own resource file with this information. But I couldn't find information anywhere about how the structure of this resource file should look, I found some content on the web, but when compiling with this resource it said that it is 16b.

Please advise how this resource should look like.

Comment: By combining [both tags Delphi and FileVersionInfo you can find existing Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi+fileversioninfo) about this. See [this A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485724/4299358) for a valid example of the resource format and a link to the documentation. Link to which "_content_" you already found and did not understand. What does "_it said that it is 16_" mean? Who says so? Is that the exact output you got?